# A and B and Chess

Tags: java

I am working on the Codeforces problem "A and B and Chess", which is as follows:

> A. A and B and Chess time limit per test 1 second memory limit per
>   test 256 megabytes input standard input output standard output
>
> A and B are preparing themselves for programming contests.
>
> To train their logical thinking and solve problems better, A and B
>   decided to play chess. During the game A wondered whose position is
>   now stronger.
>
> For each chess piece we know its weight:
>
> ```
> the queen's weight is 9,
> the rook's weight is 5,
> the bishop's weight is 3,
> the knight's weight is 3,
> the pawn's weight is 1,
> the king's weight isn't considered in evaluating position.
> ```
>
> The player's weight equals to the sum of weights of all his pieces on
>   the board.
>
> As A doesn't like counting, he asked you to help him determine which
>   player has the larger position weight. Input
>
> The input contains eight lines, eight characters each — the board's
>   description.
>
> The white pieces on the board are marked with uppercase letters, the
>   black pieces are marked with lowercase letters.
>
> The white pieces are denoted as follows: the queen is represented is
>   'Q', the rook — as 'R', the bishop — as'B', the knight — as 'N', the
>   pawn — as 'P', the king — as 'K'.
>
> The black pieces are denoted as 'q', 'r', 'b', 'n', 'p', 'k',
>   respectively.
>
> An empty square of the board is marked as '.' (a dot).
>
> It is not guaranteed that the given chess position can be achieved in
>   a real game. Specifically, there can be an arbitrary (possibly zero)
>   number pieces of each type, the king may be under attack and so on.
>   Output
>
> Print "White" (without quotes) if the weight of the position of the
>   white pieces is more than the weight of the position of the black
>   pieces, print "Black" if the weight of the black pieces is more than
>   the weight of the white pieces and print "Draw" if the weights of the
>   white and black pieces are equal. Sample test(s)
>
> ```
> Case 1
>
> Input
>
> ...QK...
> ........
> ........
> ........
> ........
> ........
> ........
> ...rk...
>
> Output
>
> White
>
>
> Case 2
>
> Input
>
> rnbqkbnr
> pppppppp
> ........
> ........
> ........
> ........
> PPPPPPPP
> RNBQKBNR
>
> Output
>
> Draw
>
>
> Case 3:
>
> Input
>
> rppppppr
> ...k....
> ........
> ........
> ........
> ........
> K...Q...
> ........
>
> Output
>
> Black
> ```
>
> Note
>
> In the first test sample the weight of the position of the white
>   pieces equals to 9, the weight of the position of the black pieces
>   equals 5.
>
> In the second test sample the weights of the positions of the black
>   and the white pieces are equal to 39.
>
> In the third test sample the weight of the position of the white
>   pieces equals to 9, the weight of the position of the black pieces
>   equals to 16.

My code is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class chess {


    private final static int QUEEN = 9;
    private final static int ROOK = 5;
    private final static int BISHOP = 3;
    private final static int KNIGHT = 3;
    private final static int PAWN = 1;
    private final static int KING = 0;


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int blackScore = 0;
        int whiteScore = 0;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        String[] input = new String[8];
        input[0] = scan.nextLine();
        input[1] = scan.nextLine();
        input[2] = scan.nextLine();
        input[3] = scan.nextLine();
        input[4] = scan.nextLine();
        input[5] = scan.nextLine();
        input[6] = scan.nextLine();
        input[7] = scan.nextLine();

        for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            if(input[i].contains("Q")) {
                whiteScore += QUEEN;
            }

            if(input[i].contains("R")) {
                whiteScore += ROOK;
            }

            if(input[i].contains("N")) {
                whiteScore += KNIGHT;
            }

            if(input[i].contains("B")) {
                whiteScore += BISHOP;
            }

            if(input[i].contains("P")) {
                whiteScore += PAWN;
            }

            if(input[i].contains("K")) {
                whiteScore += KING;
            }


            if(input[i].contains("q")) {
                blackScore += QUEEN;
            }

            if(input[i].contains("n")) {
                blackScore += KNIGHT;
            }

            if(input[i].contains("b")) {
                blackScore += BISHOP;
            }

            if(input[i].contains("p")) {
                blackScore += PAWN;
            }

            if(input[i].contains("k")) {
                blackScore += KING;
            }

            if(input[i].contains("r")) {
                blackScore += ROOK;
            }    


        }

        if(whiteScore != blackScore) {

            if(blackScore > whiteScore) {
                System.out.println("Black");
            }

            if (whiteScore > blackScore) {
                System.out.println("White");

            } 
        }else {
            System.out.println("Draw");
        }    


        System.out.println(whiteScore);
        System.out.println(blackScore);
    }

}
```

Can anyone explain what I've done wrong? Thanks!!

Comment: What are you seeing that would make it seem like this is "wrong"?

Comment: For example, both "KING" and "KNIGHT" **contain** "K".

Comment: Explain "wrong". What do you get when you run those inputs?

Comment: @PM77-1 just noticed actually. Formatting was bugging me a bit

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use the "else if" statement instead of "if", try this one, I hope this help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class chess {

private final static int QUEEN = 9;
private final static int ROOK = 5;
private final static int BISHOP = 3;
private final static int KNIGHT = 3;
private final static int PAWN = 1;
private final static int KING = 0;


public static void main(String[] args) {

    int blackScore = 0;
    int whiteScore = 0;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    String[] input = new String[8];
    input[0] = scan.nextLine();
    input[1] = scan.nextLine();
    input[2] = scan.nextLine();
    input[3] = scan.nextLine();
    input[4] = scan.nextLine();
    input[5] = scan.nextLine();
    input[6] = scan.nextLine();
    input[7] = scan.nextLine();

    for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if(input[i].contains("Q")) {
            whiteScore += QUEEN;
        }

        else if(input[i].contains("R")) {
            whiteScore += ROOK;
        }

        else if(input[i].contains("N")) {
            whiteScore += KNIGHT;
        }

        else if(input[i].contains("B")) {
            whiteScore += BISHOP;
        }

        else if(input[i].contains("P")) {
            whiteScore += PAWN;
        }

        else if(input[i].contains("K")) {
            whiteScore += KING;
        }


        else if(input[i].contains("q")) {
            blackScore += QUEEN;
        }

        else if(input[i].contains("n")) {
            blackScore += KNIGHT;
        }

        else if(input[i].contains("b")) {
            blackScore += BISHOP;
        }

        else if(input[i].contains("p")) {
            blackScore += PAWN;
        }

        else if(input[i].contains("k")) {
            blackScore += KING;
        }

        else if(input[i].contains("r")) {
            blackScore += ROOK;
        }


    }

    if(whiteScore != blackScore) {

    if(blackScore > whiteScore) {
        System.out.println("Black");
    }

    if (whiteScore > blackScore) {
        System.out.println("White");

    } 
    }else {
        System.out.println("Draw");
    }


    System.out.println(whiteScore);
    System.out.println(blackScore);
}
}
```

Comment: This is an incorrect change because each input line may have more than one type of piece

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're only including the points for *one* of a chess piece whenever *any number* of occurences of that piece is found on a line. Seeing how close you are to the solution, I think that hint alone should be enough!